# flask application with user login system but fail to handle two users at once

Tags: postgresql, flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key= os.urandom(16)

conn=psycopg2.connect( database="one",user="postgres",password="0000",host="localhost",port="5432" )
cur = conn.cursor()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select username from use")
us=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("select password from use")
psw= cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("select type from use")
ty= cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("select page from use")
page=cursor.fetchall()
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method=='POST':
        global user_name        
        user_name=request.form['username'] # make it global
        print(user_name)
        pass_word=request.form['password']     
        for i in range(len(us)):
            if user_name in us[i][0]:                    
                new=psw[i][0]
                type=ty[i][0] 
                page_access=page[i][0]  
                print(page_access)
                global page_ac
                page_ac=page_access
                page_ac=page_access.split(',')
                print(page_ac)
global x
                x=type     
                print("type:"+x)                                         
                if new==pass_word:
                    #session['user'] = 'True'
                    session['user']= request.form['username']
                    print("now u are logged in:"+session.get('user'))
                    now = session.get('user')
                    print(now)
                    cursor.execute("select page from use where username='"+str(session['user'])+"'")                   
                    page_access=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                    global page_ac
                    session['page_access']=page_access
                    print(session.get('page_access'))
                    page_ac=page_access.split(',')                                                                           
                    return render_template('analyse.html')
        else:
            return render_template('login.html',info="invalid user")                                 
    return render_template('login.html')
@app.route('/analyse',methods=['POST','GET'])
def analyse():
    global page_ac,x
    pagename="analyse"
    global user_name
    if g.user:       
        print(request.method)
        if request.method=='POST':           
            shift = request.form.get('shift1') 
            farm_chosen= request.form['Farm_chosen']           
            turbine_chosen= request.form['Turbine_chosen']                     
            timezone_chosen= request.form['Timezone']
            zoom_level= request.form['zoom_level']
            gap= request.form['gap']      
            data_set= request.form['Data_Set']                           
            map = request.form.get('Map') 
            meta= request.form.get('meta') 
            live = request.form.get('Live farm Performance')             
            status= request.form.get('Status Overview') 
            anamolies= request.form.get('Anamolies Overview') 
            turbine= request.form.get('Turbine Status Overview') 
            associate=user_name
            dt = datetime.utcnow()
            dt=dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p")

            fname = request.files ['file']      
            name = fname.filename
            print(name)
            data = open(name, 'rb')                   
          
            cur.execute("select max(id)+1 from monitor")
            id=cur.fetchone()
            id=id[0]
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.analysing(shift,farm_chosen,turbine_chosen,timezone_chosen,zoom_level,gap,data_set,map,meta,live,status,anamolies,turbine,associate,time_posted,name,id)values('"+str(shift)+"','"+str(farm_chosen)+"','"+str(turbine_chosen)+"','"+str(timezone_chosen)+"','"+str(zoom_level)+"','"+str(gap)+"','"+str(data_set)+"','"+str(map)+"','"+str(meta)+"','"+str(live)+"','"+str(status)+"','"+str(anamolies)+"','"+str(turbine)+"','"+str(associate)+"','"+str(dt)+"','"+str(name)+"','"+str(id)+"')")
            print("done")
            cur.execute('commit')
            cur.execute("SELECT * from public.analysing")
            f1=cur.fetchall()
            print(f1)
            return render_template("analyse.html",name=fname.filename,type=x)
        else:
            if pagename in session['page_access']:
                print ("welcome")
                for z in range(len(page_ac)):
                    if pagename == page_ac[z]:                            
                        return render_template('analyse.html',type=x)             
            else:
                return render_template("analyse.html")
    else:
        return render_template('login.html',info='login to traverse')
@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logout(): 
    if g.user:
        if request.method == 'GET':           
            #print(session['user'][0])
            session.pop('user',None)       
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        return redirect("monitor.html")    

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user=None
    if 'user' in session:
        g.user = session['user']
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when a user loggs in suthenticate them through db (postges) and fetch them a page.when another user comes loggs in for example if he is not allowed to see analyse.html page (inside db table i gave username with each user having diff page access each time a user comes i return this data and filter out pages they are allowed to see)
all of this is working as required including deleting usernames once user logs out.Problem im facing is when two users log in at once.lets say user one doesnot have access to page2 and user two logs in who is allowed to see page2 and user1 refreshes his page his is able to see what user 2 can. which shldnot happen how do i not let this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The user information should not be stored as a global variable.  It should be stored in the users [session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session), that way it can be accessed distinctly on each request.  You could also use something like [Flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage user loading and session management.

Comment: when i was saving user data in a session it was getting over-ridden when a new user came in, since i was using this session in accessing their page_access from db the functionality was failing.instead i used combination of cookies and session it was working. although thank you for flask-login.